# How to retrive selected value from string of dropdown markup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a string in which i have markup of drop down.I recive the string of drop down markup from server side now i have to retrive selected value.
for example i have this

```
var drop = " <select><option value=\"volvo\">Volvo</option> <option value=\"saab\" selected>Saab</option><option value=\"mercedes\">Mercedes</option><option value=\"audi\">Audi</option></select> ";
```

the variable drop has the markup of dropdown and i want the value of selected text value. In this case the "Saab" is selected and i want the its value which is "saab". So how i can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **[`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** to get `select` tag and **[`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)** to get the selected value

```js
var drop = " <select><option value=\"volvo\">Volvo</option> <option value=\"saab\" selected>Saab</option><option value=\"mercedes\">Mercedes</option><option value=\"audi\">Audi</option></select> "; 

document.write($(drop).filter('select').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Since there is only `select` tag you can just use `$(drop).val()`

```js
var drop = " <select><option value=\"volvo\">Volvo</option> <option value=\"saab\" selected>Saab</option><option value=\"mercedes\">Mercedes</option><option value=\"audi\">Audi</option></select> "; 

document.write($(drop).val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jquery, and you don't mind a little bit of overhead (from jQuery compiling the string), just doing the following should work fine:

```
var drop = " <select><option value=\"volvo\">Volvo</option> <option value=\"saab\" selected>Saab</option><option value=\"mercedes\">Mercedes</option><option value=\"audi\">Audi</option></select> "

var value = $(drop).val();
```

val() will then return the value of the selected option.